# How can I edit a m4v movie file and retain subtitles?

Tags: quicktime, mov, video-editing

I made a copy of a DVD and two sets of subtitles (Hebrew and English). Both subtitles are optional and only VLC can display them.

I am trying to edit out a scene of the movie. QuickTime can do this, but can also only save the file as a mov afterwards, which destroys the subtitles. When I edit and export to m4v, the subtitles are allegedly still there but even VLC cannot display them any more.

How can I edit an m4v file with optional subtitles without destroying the subtitles?

Answer (score 2):

Just a shot in the dark, but have a look at [VLMC](http://www.videolan.org/vlmc/). It is a non-linear video editing suite based on the VLC library, maintained by the VLC community. Otherwise, another editing software program that I know works with subtitles is [AviDemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/).

Just as a note. I am pretty sure that if you cut scenes out of the movie, you need to edit the subtitle files as well (otherwise the timing goes off). Not quite sure if any of these programs take that into consideration and modifies the subtitle files for you.

Best of luck. Hope one of these programs helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know an automated way to do it.
My suggestion : edit out the scene, resync the subtitles (.srt) with [Subfix](http://pier.morel.perso.sfr.fr/subfix/english.html), embed .srt as soft subtitles in the .m4v with [Subler](http://code.google.com/p/subler/) (so no video reencoding necessary).